# Model or ViewModel when representing a subset of data in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

If I have a complex model representing a large amount of data, and I only wish to display a cut-down version of that model (e.g. Name, Description), what is the best approach in MVVM?

Most solutions I can find seem to assume that the data is already present in memory and recommend using a new ViewModel that exposes only the fields required.

However rather than select out all of the data from the database, it would be preferable to select just what is necessary. Do I then create a new model to hold that data? Selecting directly into the ViewModel is possible but feels like the wrong thing to do. Likewise using a new model to represent a different version of the same data also feels off somehow.

What is the accepted method of doing this?

As a simple example (Simple enough class that I wouldn't ordinarily do this):

```
public class User {
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName
    public string LastName
    public int AccessLevelID
    public List<Groups> UserGroups
}
```

but I only really need:

```
public class PreviewUser {
    int UserID
    string FirstName
}
```

Comment: Don't see a problem selecting to a view model, to be honest.

Comment: My worry is it then becomes kind of separated from its 'parent' model class. Changes to the parent will not necessarily be reflected in the ViewModel. But I suppose the same is true of a cut-down model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another type with is a subset of the business type. 
usually this is known as a

**DTO - Data transfer Object** which encapsulates only what you need. so the database needs to query only the subset of the entity.

```
 public class UserDto
 {
      public int ID { get;set;}
      public string Name{ get;set;}
 }
```

Secondly if you need to add some ui logic to the display it is common to wrap the specific DTO in a more specific UI model.

```
public class UserUI 
{
     UserDTO _userDto;

     UserUI(UserDTO userDto)
     {
         _userDto = userDto;
     }

     public string Name
     {
        get{return IsAfter_21_hours ? "The user as gone home" : _userDto.Name;}
     }
}
```

the UserViewModel will reference an instance of UserUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove properties you don't need from the model (to slightly improve performance) or you can create a viewmodel that will provide only properties that you want to show.

Here is an example:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    private readonly User _user;

    public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public int UserID
    {
        get { return _user.UserID; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _user.FirstName; }
    }
}
...
var viewModels = userRepository.GetUsers().Select(user => new UserViewModel(user));
```

**UPDATED:**

If performance is really important for you, you can use inheritance. Base class will be smaller version of the data and derived class will contain complete data. You can use the base class when you need to get only some fields from DB and save bandwidth.

```
public class BaseUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseUser
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int AccessLevelID { get; set; }
    public List<Groups> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This still selects all the data from the DB before casting down into the fields required.

Comment: You can use inheritance. When you need to save bandwidth you can use base class and when you need complete data you use derived class.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of approaches you may use:

- use "full version" of source model. Since you're building UI, the user will see only what you want to display;
- use view model, and wrap source model into this view model. The implementation is trivial, and amount of data is limited before UI;
- use view model, and copy data from source model into this view model. The implementation is more complex (either mapping from existing model, or loading only required data from database), but view model and model are totally decoupled.

Actually, it depends on what is more suitable for you.

Note, that often the difference between "view model" and "model" is blurred. If the model looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...and view model - like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then throw this view model away. While there's no difference, you don't need to create extra classes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't have to create new model class to hold user data for view . Instead create a view model class and map the model properties to VM. See the example below

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    Public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
       //initialize required viewmodel properties here
    }
    int UserID {get;set;}
    string FirstName{get;set;}
}
```